# Is it mandatory to show the cookie policy notice in mobile websites?

Tags: cookies

I'm creating a website & I've used cookie on my site. So I know that, I've to create a cookie policy page but I've question regarding the cookie policy notice.

I've added cookie policy notice in my desktop site. But I'm not sure if I need to add the notice on mobile device too.

I've seen that in StackOverflow, there is a cookie policy notice in desktop site but not in mobile-view site. So my question is, can I remove the cookie notice from mobile device?

Thanks in advance.